# Flexible Web forms for data collection systems

Tags: webforms

Does anyone know of a generic framework that can be used to dynamically generate input web forms for data collection? For example, an online loan application form my require more information in 2010 than currently in 2009. Is there a way to just add a new field to the database and have it dynamically be added to a web form?
I'm using MSSQL 2005 and Adobe's ColdFusion 8 Application Server for my server-side processing. 
I realize this probably opens up a can of worms regarding style sheets, validation, and business rules... I'm just wondering if someone knows of anything to make this process more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into Extjs Library or other similar javascript libraries to generate dynamic forms.

http://www.extjs.com/deploy/ext/examples/form/dynamic.html
http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/Building-Dynamic-Web-Forms-with-the-Ext-JS-Framework/